# Click on searchView moves my LinearLayout down

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, searchview

I'm experiencing a very strange issue. When I click on the SearchView, immediately after my LinearLayout moves some pixels down, about 10 or 20. To illustrate the case I show your some screenshots.

Before clicking on SearchView:

[image]

After clicking on SearchView:

[image]

This is the OnCreateOptionsMenu method:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"OnCreateOptionsMenu-FragmentRegion");

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
        final MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView searchView= (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);


        //hint color
        SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        searchAutoComplete.setHint("Stock/Index");

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=16) {
            View searchplate = (View) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
            final Drawable searchLine = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.abc_textfield_search_material);
            searchLine.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            searchplate.setBackground(searchLine); // this method requires api level 16
        }
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        mSuggestionsAdapter =new SuggestionsAdapter(getActivity(),null,SUGGESTIONS_LOADER);
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSuggestionsAdapter);
        //on first launch will be always null, after rotating not
        if(mSearchFilter!=null) {
            MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(menuItem);
            searchView.setQuery(mSearchFilter, true);
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
                        (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)lLRegion.getLayoutParams();
                //LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
                params.topMargin=-10;
                lLRegion.setLayoutParams(params);
                lLRegion.requestLayout();


                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"OnQueryTextChange");
                mSearchFilter= TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? null: newText;
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(SUGGESTIONS_LOADER,null,FragmentRegion.this);
                return true;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
//                Cursor c= (Cursor) mSuggestionsAdapter.getItem(position);
//                c.close();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                Cursor c = (Cursor) mSuggestionsAdapter.getItem(position);
                String symbol = c.getString(SuggestionsAdapter.COL_TICKER);
                String companyName = c.getString(SuggestionsAdapter.COL_NAME);
                String securityType = c.getString(SuggestionsAdapter.COL_SECURITY_TYPE);
                ((Callback)getActivity()).onItemSelected(symbol,companyName,securityType.toUpperCase());

                //clear focus for when returning from the previous activity
                searchView.clearFocus();
                MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(menuItem);
                return true;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

As you can see I've tried to insert programatically a top margin inside onQueryTextChange method but without success.

This is the  xml

```
ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llRegion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.linearlistview.LinearListView
            android:id="@+id/indexesList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <com.linearlistview.LinearListView
            android:id="@+id/newsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to the manifest  solved my issue:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

inside the activity tag

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme1">
```